# How to create array using values from input array and another fields from hierarchy using JOLT

Tags: json, jolt

I am trying to generate the JSON output based on JSON input using JOLT.
Output should contain flatten array of objects for storing in db.
Each object should contain following fields:

- rateplan = subscriptions.subscription[].products[specification=rateplan].code
- code = subscriptions.subscription[].options[].products[].code
- mandatory = subscriptions.subscription[].options[].mandatory
- multiple = subscriptions.subscription[].options[].multiple

It can be seen from expected output that count  of objects is equal to count of subscriptions.subscription[].options[].products[]

**Input JSON** :

```json
{
    "subscriptions": {
        "subscription": [{
                "name": "TA Generated subsr1",
                "specification": "Mobile Postpaid",
                "products": [{
                        "specification": "rateplan",
                        "code": "CODE1"
                    }, {
                        "specification": "addon",
                        "code": "P2PCF"
                    }, {
                        "specification": "addon",
                        "code": "AANSK"
                    }
                ],
                "options": [{
                        "category": "Installment Plan",
                        "products": [{
                                "specification": "addon",
                                "code": "TA_CODE2"
                            }, {
                                "specification": "addon",
                                "code": "TA_CODE3"
                            }
                        ],
                        "mandatory": "false",
                        "multiple": "false"
                    }, {
                        "category": "Internet",
                        "products": [{
                                "specification": "addon",
                                "code": "TA_CODE4"
                            }
                        ],
                        "mandatory": "false",
                        "multiple": "false"
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "name": "TA Generated subsr2",
                "specification": "Mobile Postpaid",
                "products": [{
                        "specification": "rateplan",
                        "code": "CODE11"
                    }, {
                        "specification": "addon",
                        "code": "P2PCF"
                    }, {
                        "specification": "addon",
                        "code": "AANSK"
                    }
                ],
                "options": [{
                        "category": "Internet",
                        "products": [{
                                "specification": "addon",
                                "code": "TA_CODE41"
                            }
                        ],
                        "mandatory": "false",
                        "multiple": "false"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

**Expected Output JSON**:

```json
[
    {
        "rateplan": "CODE1",
        "code": "TA_CODE2",
        "mandatory": "false",
        "multiple": "false"
    },
        {
        "rateplan": "CODE1",
        "code": "TA_CODE3",
        "mandatory": "false",
        "multiple": "false"
    },
    {
        "rateplan": "CODE11",
        "code": "TA_CODE41",
        "mandatory": "false",
        "multiple": "false"
    }
    
]
```

**My jolt Spec**:

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "subscriptions": {
        "subscription": {
          "*": {
            "products": {
              "*": {
                "specification": {
                  "rateplan": {
                    "@(2,code)": "o[].rateplan"
                  }
                }
              }
            },
            "options": {
              "*": {
                "products": {
                  "*": {
                    "@(code)": "o[&1].code",
                    "@(2,mandatory)": "o[&1].mandatory",
                    "@(2,multiple)": "o[&1].multiple"
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We might concentrically evaluate with respect to the indexes of the outermost array, namely "**subscription**", as the common factor. To apply that, we can qualify the identifiers by **&7** and **&5** respectively such as

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "@subscriptions.subscription": {
        "*": {
          "options": {
            "*": {
              "products": {
                "*": {
                  "@4,products": { // loop through the OUTER "products" array
                    "*": {
                      "@code": "&7_&3.c_s.@specification" // "match" code vs. "specification"
                    }
                  },
                  "@2,category": "&5_&1.category",
                  "code": "&5_&1.product",
                  "@2,mandatory": "&5_&1.mandatory",
                  "@2,multiple": "&5_&1.multiple"
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "c_s": { "rateplan": "[#3].&" }, // filter by the key "rateplan"
        "*": { "@": "[#3].&" } // other than the previously grouped attributes
      }
    }
  }
]
```

the ***demo*** on the site http://jolt-demo.appspot.com/ is :

[image]

Comment: It works well for case when options array contains only 1 object.
In case of several objects response is incorrect.
Response will be like this:
`
[ {
  "rateplan" : [ "CODE1", "CODE1" ],
  "category" : [ "Installment Plan", "Internet" ],
  "isMandatory" : [ "false", "false" ],
  "isMultiple" : [ "false", "false" ],
  "code" : [ "TA_CODE2", "TA_CODE3" ]
} ]
`

Comment: Then, you just supplied an incomplete input. Can you please supply a complete case to reproduce it better as preventing to waste our times @StarReider

Comment: I've updated input json and expected json in description @barbaros-Özhan

Comment: Looks like we just need to add additional index for objects generayed after 1 transformation. It will be subscription index-option index-product index.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help Barbaros Özhan, proposed solution is works.
But there is small issue in it - in case of several option objects result is incorrect.

Example below:

```
[{
        "rateplan": ["CODE1", "CODE1"],
        "category": ["Installment Plan", "Internet"],
        "isMandatory": ["false", "false"],
        "isMultiple": ["false", "false"],
        "code": ["TA_CODE2", "TA_CODE3"]
    }
]
```

I've made small amendments(additional index was added) and final spec is below:

```
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "@subscriptions.subscription": {
        "*": {
          "options": {
            "*": {
              "products": {
                "*": {
                  "@4,products": { // loop through the OUTER "products" array
                    "*": {
                      "@code": "&7_&5_&3.c_s.@specification" // "match" code vs. "specification"
                    }
                  },
                  "@2,category": "&5_&3_&1.category",
                  "code": "&5_&3_&1.code",
                  "@2,mandatory": "&5_&3_&1.mandatory",
                  "@2,multiple": "&5_&3_&1.multiple"
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "c_s": { "rateplan": "[#3].&" }, // filter by the key "rateplan"
        "*": { "@": "[#3].&" } // other than the previously grouped attributes
      }
    }
  }
]
```